# data-bind style with two arrays

Tags: html, knockout.js

i have two arrays one is warning and the other is error.

what i am trying to achieve is using data.bind to read the length of the error and warning and then change the input field border to the correct color.

the typescript code behind handles the warning and errors i just need to see if i can handle the styling.

i currently have the following.

```
 <input type="text" data-bind="value: Value, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { class: WidgetType }, style: { border: Warning().length > 0 ? '3px solid #f5d531' : '2px solid #cccccc' ||  Error().length > 0 ? '3px solid #f00000' : '2px solid #cccccc' }" />
```

i was wondering if this was possible within HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible, but your expression has a bug in it. You first check your warning array. If there're warnings, you assign an orange color. So far, so good.

```js
Warning().length > 0 
  ? '3px solid #f5d531'
  : /* else case */
```

In the case of no warnings however, you have this:

```js
'2px solid #cccccc' || /* Error check */
```

Since `"2px solid #cccccc"` is a non empty string, it will never evaluate the error check after the `||`.

You probably meant to write:

```js
Warning().length > 0 ? '3px solid #f5d531' : Error().length > 0 ? '3px solid #f00000' : '2px solid #cccccc'
```

It's easy to introduce errors like these when cramming too much logic in your views. To clean things up, I'd suggest using a viewmodel with computed values. For example:

```js
// Viewmodel code
const hasError = ko.pureComputed(() => Error().length > 0);
const hasWarning = ko.pureComputed(() => Warning().length > 0);

const borderStyle = ko.pureComputed(() => {
  if (hasError()) return "3px solid #f00000";
  if (hasWarning()) return "3px solid #f5d531";
  return "2px solid #cccccc";
});
```

```html
<!-- view -->
<input type="text" data-bind="
  value: Value,
  valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',
  attr: { class: WidgetType },
  style: { border: borderStyle} " />
```

Comment: Just tried and built, and works perfectly. Thank you!